# MySQL: BIT data type always returns to 1

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, bit

I would to make an AC table with consist of 3 table field id, name, and name_bit. The name_bit field structure is should be filled by binary number with length 4 bits. I create the field with BIT data type and length is 4 -> bit(4).

After that I fill the table with some data. I fill the name_bit field with binary number 0000, but it returns in 1 and more than the 4 bit length. [Pict the table returns bit value into 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkIZ9.png)

Could you help me with this problem? I try to remove and re-create the table, and also re-install my XAMPP app but it still be the same.

Thank you.

Comment: post your code and the schema. There is no code to support the php/mysql tags.

Comment: There is something wrong somewhere - just tested it on my setup, and it works as it should - returning 0000 on the UPDATE-statement you have, and also just setting it as 0000 or 1111 or whatever else I enter.

Comment: Show the table-structure, and also, what version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: [here the structure](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0Sw3x3-aYyLWHNBU012ZjVaaXc). I'm not sure what version it is, but it's written libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev -  and I think the MySQL version is 5.0.12. Thank you for your comment @junkfoodjunkie. But I still can't figure it out, and then I decided to change the data type into CHAR.

Comment: If that's the actual version, it's SEVERELY outdated, and you should upgrade. It seems like the bit-type in your version is just a synonym for tinyint, and results may vary. You can have a look at this article: https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/04/11/bit-values-in-mysql/

Comment: I use XAMPP version 3.2.2, I still figure it out how to upgrade the MySQL in XAMPP. Thank you, for your suggestion @junkfoodjunkie

Comment: Just download the new version?

Comment: that was the latest version @junkfoodjunkie

Comment: No, the latest version of XAMPP is 5.6.30 or 7.1.1,found here: www.apachefriends.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE data_device_ac_type`?

Anyway when you `SELECT` a `BIT` datatype value, try this:

`SELECT CAST(ac_type_bit AS UNSIGNED) FROM data_device_ac_type where ac_type_id=1`

The above should give you the desired result.